# Using a JS function to use the syntax of another? node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Probably titled this one badly, will try and explain a bit better.

Basically I've been trying to make a function:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
function i(context) {
  readlineSync.question(context)
} 

var Username = i("Testing the prompt: ") 
console.log(Username)
```

I find having to write `readlineSync.question` over and over again rather irritating, but running the code returns this:

```
Testing the prompt: Hello
undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: you do know write isn't spelt wright ?

Comment: No? its correct...

Comment: yes, I made a typo. My bad. Before the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the function.

It should be:

```
function i(context) {
  return readlineSync.question(context)
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that would make sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could just do:

```
var i = readlineSync.question

// usage
i('Testing the prompt: ')
```

Creating an alias of the function

Or, if you are using an ES6 capable environment (Node 6 or Chrome):

```
import { question as i } from 'readline-sync'

// usage
i('Testing the prompt: ')
```

Which is the same of:

```
var i = require('readline-sync').question

// usage
i('Testing the prompt: ')
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I have been trying to figure out how to do the exact thing.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot the return statement

```
function i(context){
 return readlineSync.question(context)
}
```